# VB.Net Validation: Checking if Text Contains Only Letters

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, validation

Need to know how to validate a Text Box's text to make sure it contains ONLY letters without spaces.

I was hoping some sort of functions exists which could help me, something like "IsString" or something.

Comment: You can also remove whitespaces out of the string? Or do you really wanna validate the spaces in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [Regular Expression](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet)

```
if System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, "^[A-Za-z]+$")) ...
```

**Edit**

The `^ $` character are *anchors*; they mean match the *start* and *end-of-line* respectively and can be used to prevent sub-string/partial matches.

E.g. The regex `X` would match `"X"` and `"AAAXAAA"` but `^X$` only matches `"X"` as its value can be thought of as `"<start of line>X<end of line>"`

Comment: Thankyou, I know how to use Regex using javascript but never encountered it before with VB.Net, poor experience and foresight on by behalf. 

You've done enough for me already, but if you the intricacies, could you possibly explain to me what each section of the RegEx ("^[A-Za-z]+$")means? 

I think I understand the letters and the "$", they're for comparing the contents to letters(upper and lower case) and symbols, but what is the "^" for?

Comment: Actually `^$` are the same in JS, `/x/` is just a shorthand for `new RegExp("x")`

Answer (score 2):

This will prevent anything from being typed into the TextBox except letters.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True  'ignore everything but letter keys
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, this solves my problem well but it differs slightly from my style and the general style already built into the solution I'm making (for school). However, I appreciate your time, and I will defo take this away with me :D

Comment: If you do this don't forget to deal with pastes as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, like this:

```
Return (New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$")).IsMatch(testValue)
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is going to be a similar comment as my comment to the above answer but, I noticed your RegEx is different to the above. Why? What does the "{1,}" do?

Comment: @Jason -- that means repeat the preceding value -- in this case any letter from `a` to `z` or `A` to `Z` -- at least 1 time with no upper bound.  To clarify this more: if you used `{1,5}` instead, it would mean at least 1 time and at most 5 times, or if you used `{0,5}` it would mean no lower bound but at most 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple:

```
Char.isletter(textboxname)

If char.isletter(textboxname)=false then
Msgbox(error message)
Textboxname.clear()
Textboxname.focus()
End if
```

Comment: `char.isletter` accepts all ASCII characters. This can be a bad thing if you're expecting only the alphabet.