# Visual Basics Game Build Errors, How to Deal with WithEvents?

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I just posted the current code of mine. However I got this error: Error 1   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\dicegamefolder\NewDiceBattleGame\NewDiceBattleGame\Form1.vb    12  117 NewDiceBattleGame

How can I fix that issue of mine so I oculd see the dice roll and I could see the outcomes and scores? I made changes to my old code and it still is not working the way I want it too. If anyone could stay with me on this question until I get the whole game working right I will really, really appreciate your help. Thanks again as always and hope to hear from you all soon!

I will post a snapshot of my GUI, my code, and the instructions for the game. Thanks again everyone for your help!

http://imageshack.com/a/img673/5584/jV0f0c.png

A human player is playing against a computer using VB's built in random number generator. The objective of the game is for either opponent to have a higher score than the other to win the game in a best of an odd number of matches format from 1 up to 99 ( like 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 and so forth).

The instructions are: 1. The input number of matches must be checked for validity, a message box must pop up with the appropriate message to indicate that the input is invalid. A popup must show if the input is invalid. 2. Once the game starts, the Best of Games input box (text box) should be disabled (or grayed out) until the Restart button is pressed or the match ends. 3. Either opponents score must be tracked, follow the Game User Interface screenshot format and other details below. The PC vs You boxes (labels) should display the current scores. 4.The Outcome boxes (label) should display who won the current game or if there is a tie (i.e. "You Win", "PC Wins", "Its a tie"). 5. Each of the Roll Total Boxes (label) should display the total of the PC's and the human player's roll accordingly. 6. Only games with one score higher than the other count, tied games do not. 7. The following message box pop ups should come up depending on the outcome of the set. 8. Pressing the Exit button should show the following popup: Do you want to exit?

```
 Public Class DiceBattle

Dim randomObject As New Random() 'Create Random object
Dim BestOfGamesCounter As Integer
Dim PC As Integer = 0
Dim You As Integer = 0

Private Function GetRandom() As Integer
    Return randomObject.Next(1, 7)
End Function

Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True 'ignore everything but letter keys
End Sub

Private Sub RollButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RollButton.Click
    If CInt(GameTextBox.Text) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Number of Games > 0", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Application.Restart()
    End If

    If CInt(GameTextBox.Text) > 0 Then
        BestOfGamesCounter = Convert.ToInt32(GameTextBox.Text)
    End If


    Dim tempRandom As Integer = GetRandom()
    PC1.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
    PC = PC + tempRandom
    tempRandom = GetRandom()
    PC2.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
    PC = PC + tempRandom
    PC3.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
    PC = PC + tempRandom
    tempRandom = GetRandom()
    You4.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
    PC = You + tempRandom
    You5.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
    You = You + tempRandom
    tempRandom = GetRandom()
    You6.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
    PC = You + tempRandom
    If (PC > You) Then
        'You lost
    ElseIf (PC = You) Then
        'Tie
    Else
        'You win
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayDie(diePictureBox As PictureBox)

    Dim face As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 7)

    ' adjust pip count to image index by subtracting one
    diePictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(face - 1)

End Sub


Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Dim RESPONSE As MsgBoxResult
    RESPONSE = MsgBox("Do you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question)
    If RESPONSE = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Me.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub GameTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GameTextBox.TextChanged
    If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
        Do
            MsgBox(GameTextBox.Text + " round(s) will be played, enjoy!")
        Loop While GameTextBox.Text = "STOP"
    End If
    GameTextBox.Enabled = False
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VBA is a completely different language from the one in your question: please fix your tags.

Comment: Okay fixed. So what is the solution towards getting the dices to roll and the scores and messages to show up? I've been trying out different things but none of them worked.

Comment: get rid of the If/End If block and see if it works...`If GameTextBox.Text <= "0" Then...` is a nonsense evaluation.  Option Strict strongly advised

Comment: I already turned on Option Strict already Plutonix. Not sure why it is still not working. I will get rid of the if/end if block though and i will let you know if it works or not in a minute.

Comment: Plutonix if you were referring to If GameTextBox.Text <= "0" Then... then I already got rid of that part already. I did'nt even include that part of the code in this new posting. I still have Private Sub GameTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GameTextBox.TextChanged
    If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
        Do
            MsgBox(GameTextBox.Text + " round(s) will be played, enjoy!")
        Loop While GameTextBox.Text = "STOP"
    End If
    GameTextBox.Enabled = False
End Sub , but I need that part though right? I ran it again and it still does not work.

Comment: well, there is still an If/End If in the code posted which is all we can go by.  If you have pictureboxes named PC1, PC2, PC3 it should work at runtime

Comment: Well I got rid of Private Sub GameTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GameTextBox.TextChanged If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then Do MsgBox(GameTextBox.Text + " round(s) will be played, enjoy!") Loop While GameTextBox.Text = "STOP" End If GameTextBox.Enabled = False End Sub, but after I ran it it still didn't work. Also, how do you get a project to run at runtime? Is that basically the same thing as pressing the green start button with debug? Or is it something else because I want to see if it works in that way.

Comment: Okay I ran it, and when I pressed the roll button I got this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid., what caused that to happen and how can I fix it so I could get the dice to roll? I will replace the old code I have above with the current code so you could see what I have now. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I just ran into another error: this time its this Error 1 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\dicegamefolder\NewDiceBattleGame\NewDiceBattleGame\Form1.vb 12 117 NewDiceBattleGame
How can I fix this error and finally get my whole game to work? Please be specific as in what object should I click on and enter a code for that particular object in my form in order for everything to run smoothly and achieving the main objectives of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Lines like this,

```
If GameTextBox.Text <= "0" Then
```

and this,

```
If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
```

can lead to unpredictable results. What this is trying to do is compare a string (the text in the TextBox) numerically with another string (the "0"). That doesn't make much sense, and even though VB.Net Uzis pretty good at figuring things out, sometime it has no idea what you are trying to do.

Always do your own explicit conversions, instead of leaving it up to the compiler:

```
If CInt(GameTextBox.Text) <= 0 Then
```

and,

```
If CInt(GameTextBox.Text) > 0 Then
```

Notice the explicit conversion of the Text property to an Integer, and the lack of quotation marks around the zeros. This allows the compiler to do a direct numerical comparisson without any uncertainty. This should fix your issue with the application restarting after entering "1" in the TextBox.

---

In order to display game results (like "You Win!") you'll have to keep track of the values of your dice rolls. One way would be to create a value for each player. At the top of your class, this might look something like:

```
Dim dicePC As Integer = 0
Dim dicePlayer As Integer = 0
```

You can then tally each dice roll in these variables. I would rearrange things a little bit..

```
Private Function GetRandom() As Integer
    Return randomObject.Next(1, 7)
End Function
```

Then, at the end of `RollButton_Click`:

```
Dim tempRandom As Integer = GetRandom
PC1.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
dicePC = dicePC + tempRandom
tempRandom = GetRandom
PC2.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
dicePC = dicePC + tempRandom
```

and so on, for the other four dice...

Then you will have two variables containing the score of the dice rolls, which you can compare.

```
If (dicePC > dicePlayer) Then
    'You lost
ElseIf (dicePC = dicePlayer) Then
    'Tie
Else
    'You win
End If
```

---

Using these tips should get you a little further.

---

EDIT: to address your InvalidCastException

It sounds like something in your TextBox can't be converted to an integer, causing the error. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126257/vb-net-validation-checking-if-text-contains-only-letters/27126398#27126398) I propose a solution using `IsLetter` for ensuring that only alphabetic characters be allowed to be typed into a specific TextBox. You can use this technique in a similar way on any of your TextBoxes where you expect only numeric input by checking `Char.IsDigit`. Be sure to copy that line into the correct button's KeyPress handler.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True  'ignore everything but number keys
End Sub
```

---

Additionally, your dice roll code was a little misled. You are still adding to the `dicePC` score, when you should be adding to `diceYou`. Try this:

```
Dim tempRandom As Integer = GetRandom()
PC1.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
dicePC = dicePC + tempRandom
tempRandom = GetRandom()
PC2.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
dicePC = dicePC + tempRandom
tempRandom = GetRandom()
PC3.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
dicePC = dicePC + tempRandom
tempRandom = GetRandom()
You4.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
diceYou = diceYou + tempRandom
tempRandom = GetRandom()
You5.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
diceYou = diceYou + tempRandom
tempRandom = GetRandom()
You6.Image = ImageList1.Images(tempRandom - 1)
diceYou = diceYou + tempRandom
```

You can also remove all of the old calls to `DisplayDie` including the function itself:

```
DisplayDie(PC1)
```

---

EDIT: The error on line 12 is because you copy/pasted the code I provided without renaming the function. This line:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
```

The two places it says "TextBox" need to be renamed to whatever you call the TextBox where you input the number of games. I think you called yours `GameTextBox`, and so, the line should read something like:

```
Private Sub GameTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles GameTextBox.KeyPress
```

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the tips. I'm going to try it out now and see if it works. I will let you know in a minute if the game works or if I still need some help. Talk to you in a little bit!

Comment: Okay I ran it, and when I pressed the roll button I got this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid., what caused that to happen and how can I fix it so I could get the dice to roll? I will replace the old code I have above with the current code so you could see what I have now. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Justin , so where would I add that code into my form? I'm asking that because I already added that code into my form however I got an error saying this: Error 1 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\dicegamefolder\NewDiceBattleGame\NewDiceBattleGame\Form1.vb 12 117 NewDiceBattleGame

Comment: So Justin, I just replace all the PC1, PC2, ...You5, You6 with DisplayDie(PC1), DisplayDie(PC2), DisplayDie(You5), DisplayDie(You6)? do I also change the diceYou's and the dicePC's?

Comment: No, you can now remove all of the DisplayDie(...) calls as you no longer need them.

Comment: Okay I will try that I will let you know in a minute if the game works or not still.

Comment: I'm still getting build errors with that handles clause error once I ran it. I even got rid of all 6 of the DisplayDie(...). What do we do now Justin? I will post the current code up above the beginning of my post to show you where I'm at now. P.S. Do you want to take this discussion to a chat so it could be easier for you and I to work on this together because I'm pretty sure I'm almost done with this game, I just need to fix a few things here in there. If your not interested ion doing that, thats fine. Just keep in mind I will be posting/adding new comments very frequently here.

Comment: What line is your error on? Also, you seem to have renamed the `dicePC` and `diceYou` variables to `PC` and `You` respectively. You need to do this for all of them, including the ones at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Hey Justin, check my current code now and tell me what you think of it. That one error I got was in line 12.

Comment: @Anonymous Updated to show why there was an error on line 12.